# Can't login in 2 accounts in Instagram using Android Emulators (Returning Blank Dialog)

Tags: applications, genymotion, instagram

I have two phones S7 and S8 (Android Genymotion Emulators) that I want to use with the same Instagram account.

On the first phone, I'm able to log in with my username and password. However, when I tried using the same username and password on the second device, it won't let me log in. It's returning a blank dialog with a dismiss button at the bottom of the dialog.

[image]

**WHAT I TRIED SO FAR:**
I tried the same scenario using Android Studio Emulators instead of Genymotion, but it did not work.
I tried with different devices with Genymotion, (Nexus 5X and S7), but it did not work.

Comment: What's the app you're trying to use on the phones: the official Instagram app, or some third-party app? It may be that this is just a bug in the app, and the only solution is to report it to the developer.

Comment: It's the official Instagram app.